# How to get a control to fill its container up to its maximum size, then center align

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout

I have a Windows Forms application consisting of a control within a window. I'd like the width of the control to fill the width of the form up to its `MaximumSize.Width`, at which point it centers itself within the window. Is there a way I can do this without code behind, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the designer, center the control on its parent vertically, then strech the control to fill its parent horizontally.

Then alter the `Anchor` property of the control to `Left; Right`.

Now your control stays centered vertically while always filling its parent horizontally.

If that's not what you're looking for feel free to clarify.